# AuthenticateAsServerAsync hangs

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, networking, server

I'm using

```
await stream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(serverCert, true, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
```

In my application to secure a connection.
Unfortunately in rare cases (roughly one out of 1000) this hangs completely.
I tried to set timeouts on the lower level `NetworkStream` and the `TcpClient`.

But nothing works, those connections keep accumulating over time.

And by it hangs completely I mean it gets stuck inside there for days (if the application runs that long).

I currently solved this with a dirty hack. Im starting a new thread, wait 5seconds inside it, and if the call didnt return in time I call `tcpClient.Close()` to force the SslStream to abort.

Whats the issue here?
What is the intended way to handle scenarios like this in general where you need a timeout on a function but there is no overload that takes a TimeSpan or CancellationToken?

Shouldnt the lower level timeouts on the tcpClient at least throw an exception? Why is that not happening either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reason

Seems like the async versions of all network related stuff does not support timeouts.
Thats why AuthenticateAsServerAsync does not support timeouts either.

From the documentation:

> Note
>
> This property affects only synchronous reads performed by calling the Read method. This property does not affect asynchronous reads performed by calling the BeginRead method.

### How I solved it

Before I start AuthenticateAsServerAsync(...) I first start my own Task with an delay.

```
Task.Run(async() {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    tcpClient.Close();
});
```

If someone has a better way to do this please let me know :)