# AuthenticateAsServerAsync is failing

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

Accepting connections from browsers AJAX requests and establishing secure connection:

```
var task = _stream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(serverCertificate);
if (!task.Wait(60000, ct)) throw new Exception("Timeout");
```

one from ~20 clients with new browsers are disconnecting at this stage or connection times out. What can be wrong with this?

Comment: Another person on S/O said timeouts don't seem to work with this fn. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897425/authenticateasserverasync-hangs

Comment: From my observations task wait method is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this problem occur because browsers establish additional connections and not establishing ssl/tls. So everything works as expected and have to keep in mind that on AuthenticateAsServerAsync can be long waitings and timeouts.

Comment: Are you saying that AuthenticateAsServerAsync doesn't need to return for an SslStream to work properly?  If so, do you have any documentation to back that up?  I'm running into the same issue, but I'd need to show some proof.

Comment: Browsers are pooling tcp connections for future use and in most cases they do not use it.